# Optimaze Mysql Query Group Concat with Left Join

Tags: php, mysql

here is my query

```
select image_tree.id, image_tree.parent_id, image_tree.url,
                           CONCAT(
                                '[',
                               GROUP_CONCAT(
                              JSON_OBJECT(
                                 'lang', image_tree_title.lang,
                                 'title', image_tree_title.title
                                   )
                          ), ']'
                       ) AS lang from `image_tree` 
left join `image_tree_title` on `image_tree_title`.`image_tree_id` = `image_tree`.`id` 
group by `image_tree`.`url`, `image_tree`.`id` 
order by url + 0 ASC
```

I was given advice to remove GROUP_CONCAT and sort data in PHP. Will GROUP_CONCAT have significant impact on performance, What is better approach, i think that it way better to prepare all data in MYSQL and no need for additional loops in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really are better off just querying for the fields you need and assembling them client side. Your current GROUP_CONCAT AND JSON_OBJECT approach puts more work on the database server, locks the tables longer, and increased the amount of data that has to be packaged up and sent from the database to client code. Unless MySQL has some magic compression going on within the connection or special packing for JSON objects, it is going to be passing back numerous, redundant copies of your column name (along with formatting) for each data value you are retrieving.

I wouldn't say *never* use GROUP_CONCAT, it can even be used to do work that could be too expensive on particularly weak clients.... but it does come with overhead; a raw INT like `10000` can basically be sent in 4 bytes, but best case scenario a string `10000` takes 5 bytes. JSON adds even more overhead; while GROUP_CONCAT expands smaller datatypes, and adds a little more for separators, JSON does that and adds redundant field naming syntax.

Sorting in SQL is fine though, it's what it was built for (though I think that is even avoided when possible in extremely high demand systems).

Comment: I would say it depends on the application and if this is part of a process or not, and how many rows are coming back.  Its just a select.  I don't like adding extra tools like PHP personally unless I am forced to do so.  There are profiling tools for things like this.

Comment: @ggb667 True. If there are multiple clients in different languages, it can make sense to do this in the database to standardize the data seen by the different clients (if all clients actually benefit from having the data in JSON format). I was mainly operating under the assumption that the php code the question referred to is actually the "client" and not an intermediate layer. to be used just for formatting the data coming back.

Comment: so overall in this case is better to use php for formatting? I have like 30, 40 rows in database.

Comment: With that little data it is probably not really a concern either way; this is more of an issue when you are dealing with results with at least "thousands" of rows.

Comment: It all comes down to how often this happens.  Given that is is just a select, if this is infrequent I don't see why PHP is needed.

Comment: @ggb667 I am pretty sure in this case "PHP" is synonymous with "client code".

Comment: Looks like we have two different approaches, that's why asked i am confused also.

Comment: What about JS? MYSQL PHP JS?

Comment: The advice pretty much goes for any application code. If your application is not written in php, I would not make a separate intermediate php layer to do the conversion; but if your application is already in php, or already has an intermediate php layer, I would suggest handling it in php. But so little data expected, doing it the way you are currently is fine too.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that if you're using php to prepare data for javascript executing in a users browser, you may want to consider that putting it in JSON format will also inflate the size of the html/javascript sent, increasing bandwidth usage and consequently page load times. _All that said, I've never been overly fond of bloaty formats like XML and JSON. They have their place when different versions of software may be talking to each other with slightly different data formats; but when a client is querying a non-JSON source directly, I don't really see much benefit._

Comment: tried to add like 100k rows in first table, with group concat takes 0.8 sec without 0.5, looks like group concat has significant impact.